# A curve where all tangent lines are concurrent must be straight line

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to solve this question in the classical [Do Carmo's differential geometry book](http://www.math.uni.lodz.pl/~maczar/ggk/do%20Carmo,%20Differential%20Geometry%20of%20Curves%20and%20Surfaces.pdf) (page 23):

> 5. A regular parametrized curve $\alpha$ has the property that all its tangent lines pass through a fixed point. Prove that the trace of $\alpha$ is a (segment of a) a straight line.

**My attempt**

Following the statement of the question, we have $\alpha(t)+\lambda(s)\alpha'(s)=const$.

Taking the derivative of both sides we have $\alpha'(s)+\lambda'(s)\alpha'(s)+\lambda(s)\alpha''(s)=0$ which is equal to $(1+\lambda'(s))\alpha'(s)+\lambda(s)\alpha''(s)=0$.

Since $\alpha'(s)$ and $\alpha''(s)$ are linearly independent, we have $\lambda'(s)=-1$ and $\lambda(s)=0$ for every $s$ which I found strange, since the derivative of the zero function is zero.

I need a clarification at this point and a hand to finish my attempt of solution.

Comment: Why do you think that the velocity and acceleration vectors are linearly independent? For a particle accelerating along a line, the velocity and acceleration vectors are parallel.

Comment: @symplectomorphic because they are perpendicular with each other

Comment: They are perpendicular only if you are parametrizing by arclength, which you did not say. Take the curve $r(t)=\langle t^2, 0\rangle$. The velocity is $\langle 2t, 0\rangle$ and the acceleration is $\langle 2, 0\rangle$. Obviously these vectors aren't perpendicular.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I'm sorry, it's parametrized by arc length.

Comment: @symplectomorphic one question. Do you think I can take the derivative of $\lambda$? I don't know in the $\lambda$ is differentiable or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you assumed that $\alpha$ is parametrized by arc length (or constant length), so $|\alpha'(s)|=1$ and differentiating gives $\langle \alpha' , \alpha''\rangle = 0$. Thus, if $\alpha''(s)\neq \vec 0$, then $\alpha'(s), \alpha''(s)$ are linearly independent.

So like you said, you find $\lambda (s) = 0$ and $\lambda'(s) = -1$ whenever $\alpha''(s)\neq 0$.

The set $\{ s : \alpha''(s)\neq \vec 0\}$ is an open set. If it is nonempty, it contains some intervals $I$. But your assertion on $\lambda$ cannot be true on an interval. Thus

$$\{ s : \alpha''(s)\neq \vec 0\}$$

is empty. So $\alpha''\equiv \vec 0$ and $\alpha$ defines a straight line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why my assertion on $\lambda$  can't be true on an interval?

Comment: @user42912 if $\lambda$ is a constant function on an interval then it's derivatives is 0

Comment: Thank you again. Out of curiosity, If $\lambda$ is constant on a different domain, could the function be different than zero? Do you have some example of such function?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the tangents pass trough the point $c$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then we the vectors $\alpha(s) - c$ and $\alpha'(s)$ are proportional, that is
$(\alpha(s)-c)  + \lambda(s) \alpha'(s)=0$
for some scalar function $\lambda(s)$. Replacing $\alpha(s)$ with $\alpha(s) - c$, we may assume that $c=0$, that is
$$\alpha(s)
  + \lambda(s) \alpha'(s)=0$$

The set $\{s \ | \ \lambda(s) \ne 0\}$ is open and dense in the domain (since the curve is regular).  On this domain  we can write
$$\alpha'(s) = \mu(s) \alpha(s)$$
and so on each connected component
$$\alpha(s) = e^{M(s)} \cdot \mathbb{a}$$
where $M(s)$ is an antiderivative of $\mu(s)$. It is now easy to conclude (since $\gamma$ is regular) that the vector constants $\mathbb{a}$ are the same for all the connected components. Therefore, $\gamma$  describes a (part of ) the line of direction $\mathbb{a}$ through the origin.