# Suppose that all the tangent lines of a regular plane curve pass through some fixed point. Prove that the curve is part of a straight line.

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, tangent-line

**Question.** Suppose that all the tangent lines of a regular plane curve pass through some fixed point. Prove that the curve is part of a straight line. Prove the same result
if all the normal lines are parallel.

I am working on differential geometry from the book by Pressley and I have a doubt in the solution of the above question whose (brief) solution is given by:

**Solution:** We can assume that the curve $\gamma$ is unit-speed and that the tangent lines all pass
through the origin (by applying a translation to $\gamma$). Then, there is a scalar $\lambda(t)$
such that $\gamma'(t) = \lambda(t)\gamma(t)$ for all $t$. Then, $\gamma '' = \lambda'\gamma   + \lambda \gamma' = (\lambda' + \lambda^2)\gamma$.

Can anyone please explain me how does this line follow : " Then, there is a scalar $\lambda(t)$
such that $\gamma'(t) = \lambda(t)\gamma(t)$ for all $t$."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $-1/\lambda(t)$ is the solution to $\gamma(x)+t\gamma '(x)=0$ which exists by assumption.

Comment: It seems this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468583/a-curve-where-all-tangent-lines-are-concurrent-must-be-straight-line), among others.